# Convert or move personal outlook to public folder

Tags: exchange, outlook, public-folders

A user has a personal calendar (on exchange, not in a pst) that needs to be converted, moved, or copied to the public folder so that everyone can access it.  Once done, the user does not need to keep a personal copy any more.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working.  This is what I did:

1. As admin, create a folder, call it "Test" under Public Folders.
2. Assign the user to Owner of this folder.
3. As the user, copy the personal calendar to "Test" and then give the admin user 'Owner' to this calendar
4. As admin, rename and then move the calendar up one level so that it is directly underneath Public Folders, thus making the "Test" folder empty.  I then removed this folder.
5. As the user, delete all items out of their personal calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this from within Outlook.  In outlook 2010 go to the calendar, under the folder tab (top menu) you will see an option to "Share Calendar".  You will also need to set proper calendar permissions for other people to be able to view this person's personal calendar.  You amy also be able to assign certain people permission to create any new appointments for this person.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Is it allowing you to switch to Folders view and right-click on the calendar you want to copy? Select copy from the pop-up menu.  In the folder dialog that pops-up can you browse down to Public Folders? You have to make sure that you have create/write access to this folder.